# vue-cli-service build fails with 0 errors

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

Is there a way to track down this kind of build problem?  I.e. a flag that would show more detailed error information?  My project is very much like the default vue cli project.  It has been working fine for months until this morning.

```
$ vue-cli-service build --mode dev

⠏  Building for dev...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 0 errors                                                     12:06:07 PM

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I had a file called worker.js which is a web worker being loaded by worker-loader.  In worker.js I import a second .js file which imports a missing .js file (due to my error).  For whatever reason, this error doesn't make it to the surface of vue-cli-service build.